# JSON & API call is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn about basic API calls; I'm having issue with 'dialing in' to specific array objects in this Star Wars API.

I can console.log(json.people) or (json.planets), but cannot seem to go further than this, i.e. console.log(json.people.results) to show me an array of characters and associated data, as this shows as undefined...

I have attempted to parse / stringify the json, but am hitting a wall...

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

```js
function getData() {

    url = "https://swapi.dev/api/?format=json";
    fetch(url).then((Response) => {
            return Response.json();
        })

        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json.people.results);
            console.log(json.planets);
        });      
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

This endpoint returns list of API's. So I take one of those and make another API call. You can skip the first step.

```js
function getData() {

  var url = "https://swapi.dev/api/?format=json";
  fetch(url)
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json)

      var url = json.people;
      fetch(url)
        .then((Response) => Response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(json)
        });

    });
}

getData();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```